# Relationship between supremums

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are supremums of $|f(x)|, |f'(x)|, |f''(x)|$ respectively over $(0,\infty)$, then what is the relationship between $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ ?

It was asked by a friend like a puzzle and hence was posed as an informal question to me.

My thoughts are that there should exist a relation between them such that if any two are given, we can find the third one.

Comment: over which domain are we taking sup ?

Comment: @SaikatPanja Although he asked me just that, but I suppose $(0,\infty)$ will do. Edited the question.

Comment: Are they the only local suprema?  We know f'($\alpha$) = 0 and f''($\alpha$) < 0 and f''($\beta$) = 0 and f'''($\beta$) < 0.  If these are the only local suprema than these are the only points that are 0 so $\gamma$ < $\beta$ < $\alpha$ .  I think.  I'm too tired to work out the details.  I suppose we'd have to rule out the possibility of some of the functions having infs.

Comment: @fleablood Since it was asked during an informal talk so I don't have information regarding the nature of the supremums, but I don't think it's about finding the order in which they increase or decrease, there should be a relation where, if two of them are given we can find the third (which is my line of thinking).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's an ordering problem with $\gamma < \beta < \alpha$.

$f''(\beta) = 0  $ so $f''(\gamma) > 0$ (as $\gamma$ is a sup and $\gamma = \beta = 0$ would mean $\beta$ is a saddle-point, not, sup of $f'$).  So $f' $ is increasing at $\gamma$ so $\beta > \gamma$ (as $f'(\beta) > f'(\gamma)$ )

Exact same reasoning shows $\alpha > \gamma$.

This assumes f is continuous and that these are global suprema.  It also assumes this is what "relation" means.

Answer (score 0):

I expect there is no relation. Function $f(x)=S\arctan(kx) $ can achieve a large supremum with a slow growth (big $S$, small $k$), or it can make a sudden, small jump (when $S$ is small and $k$ large).